# How to take element-wise logarithm of a matrix in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Working with a sympy Matrix or numpy array of sympy symbols, how does one take the element-wise logarithm?

For example, if I have:

```
m=sympy.Matrix(sympy.symbols('a b c d'))
```

Then `np.abs(m)` works fine, but `np.log(m)` does not work ("AttributeError: log").

Any solutions?

Comment: Please post the exact traceback.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that is the exact traceback I get.

Comment: Python's tracebacks are usually 4-5 lines long.

Comment: @Bitwise See [this issue on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1611). Apparently, you can't use `numpy.log` on object arrays (e.g. sympy arrays).

Comment: @senshin thanks. So this means that there is no way to take the logarithm of a sympy array/matrix?

Comment: @Bitwise Are we talking about an actual matrix logarithm (inverse of the matrix exponential) or an element-wise logarithm? I ask because the matrix `m` you've defined is not square (it's 1-by-4), so it doesn't have a matrix log.

Comment: @senshin element-wise, like I wrote in the question.

Comment: @Bitwise Oops, sorry, reading comprehension failure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Matrix.applyfunc`:

```
In [6]: M = sympy.Matrix(sympy.symbols('a b c d'))

In [7]: M.applyfunc(sympy.log)
Out[7]:
⎡log(a)⎤
⎢      ⎥
⎢log(b)⎥
⎢      ⎥
⎢log(c)⎥
⎢      ⎥
⎣log(d)⎦
```

You can't use `np.log` because that does a numeric log, but you want the symbolic version, i.e., `sympy.log`.

Comment: Hey, just saw you are the lead developer of sympy - respect! Good job. It would be great if the matrix vectorization was more streamlined similar to Matlab symbolic toolbox.

Comment: Well, I didn't write most of the code, though. There have been a ton of contributors.

Comment: If you have any suggestion to make it better, let us know.

Comment: is there a way to pass in the base for log?

Comment: The base is given as a second argument to log, but for now, it just divides by `log(base)`, so `log(x, y)` just gives `log(x)/log(y)`. So in this case you could use `M.applyfunc(sympy.log)/sympy.log(base)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an elementwise logarithm, and your matrices are all going to be single-column, you should just be able to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> m = sympy.Matrix(sympy.symbols('a b c d'))
>>> logm = sympy.Matrix([sympy.log(x) for x in m])
>>> logm
Matrix([
[log(a)],
[log(b)],
[log(c)],
[log(d)]])
```

This is kind of ugly, but you could wrap it in a function for ease, e.g.:

```
>>> def sp_log(m):
    return sympy.Matrix([sympy.log(x) for x in m])

>>> sp_log(m)
Matrix([
[log(a)],
[log(b)],
[log(c)],
[log(d)]])
```

Comment: Thanks - so no vectorized solution I guess. I hoped sympy would be a good replacement for Matlab symbolic stuff but I see sympy isn't there yet in terms of handling matrices.